# Looking for a VS Code snippet that automatically inserts a modification date value upon saving

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Well, that's the idea, to find a VS Code snippet/extension that automatically inserts a customizable timestamp where indicated by a placeholder or something, so you could forget (as indeed I do most of the times and hence my search ) about having to manually update something like that.

I normally use something like `local build = "20031005-1803"` as part of versioning my Lua scripts and I know about the existence of this kind of snippets: [Insert Date String](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsynowiec.vscode-insertdatestring) for inserting datetime manually, but I'm unable to find one that automates the process like described (assuming it's possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lpubsppop01.vscode-auto-timestamp#:~:text=Update%20timestamp%20in,Install](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lpubsppop01.vscode-auto-timestamp#:%7E:text=Update%20timestamp%20in,Install) that seems to do exactly this. It tracks create time and update time of file on save.

[image]

Comment: It seems exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Unfortunately, I'm having trouble to get it work under my style requirements even though there's a review with a use sample like this:
`Settings: 
Modified Start Time = [lL]ast* ?[mM]odified+ ?[=:']
Code: 
var module1NameLastModified = '2022-02-06 04:08';`
`
Do you know where I could find more details about how to construct those kind of patterns by any chance? Because every thing I try in base of those few examples fail...

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to get it! (Although a little more documentation from devs part wouldn't have hurt ). The main problem was that, for some reason, VS Code wasn't updating correctly the changes I was making into the extension settings, but after restarting the program those changes started to take place, and of course that made a difference, haha... Lesson learned. Well, thank you again!